# jQuery Save text has csv, Trim and split from div, not table

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to save a bunch of div's as a CSV file to generate a report, The script seems to be working great.

The only problem is that i get a one liner has an output, i've tried to trim, split and join in many different variations, and don't seem to be getting the right outcome, was hoping someone could enlighten me on the return `var csv = jQuery("#exportDivs").map(function (a, i) { return $(this).text().split("[split]");}).toArray().join("\r\n");`

Javascript:

```
var csv = jQuery("#exportDivs").map(function (a, i) {
  return $(this).text().split("[split]");
}).toArray().join("\r\n");

document.write(csv)

var download = function (content, fileName, mimeType) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { 
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], { type: mimeType }), fileName);
} else if ('download' in a) { 
    a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);
    a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    setTimeout(function () {
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 66);
    return true;
} else { //do iframe dataURL download (old ch+FF):
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(f);
    }, 333);
    return true;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table" id="exportDivs">
  <div class="row heading">
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        Data Title 1
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
        Data Title 2
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
        Data Title 3
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
        Data Title 4
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a onclick="download(csv, 'downloadmrzik.csv', 'text/csv');">Download Me</a>
    </div>

</div>
[split]


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            DATA Result 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            DATA Result 2
         </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            DATA Result 3
         </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            DATA Result 4
         </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">

        </div>

        </div>

[split]
</div>
```

Outcome on .csv file

`DataTitle1 DataTitle2 DataTitle3 DataTitle4 DataResult1 DataResult2 DataResult3 DataResult4`

Comment: What outcome do you want? Do you want the same as the current outcome but just split at the spaces into individual lines? Do you want a single line, but with commas between the words (after all, you do seem to want [c]omma-[s]eparated-[v]alue format)? Do you want the `DataTitle...` entries separated by commas, the `DataResult...` entries separated by commas, but the two lists separated by a newline? Do you want the text `"Download Me"` included somewhere?

Comment: Note that the `map` function you use operates on arrays, and the `jQuery` function you use returns an object. Do you want the `jQuery` function to return a single jQuery object that contains the single div with the id `exportDivs` or do you want the function to return an array of all the divs nested within that outer div (which would return two `row` divs) or even of all the divs nested within those (which would return 10 doubly-nested divs)?